# How to revert a snapshot in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I made a snapshot in VirtualBox, how do I revert back to it?

Answer (score 7):

If you select the virtual machine in the left hand column, you should see a tab called "snapshots" on the left.

Simply click the snapshot you want and then launch it!

Answer (score 1):

If looking to restore the snapshot via the terminal:

`VBoxManage snapshot <virtual-machine-name> restore <snapshot-name>`